# Find maximum length of data in keys for the collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59786a62a96166007d7e364dsadasfafsdfsdgdfgfd"),
  "someotherdata" : {
    "place1" : "lwekjfrhweriufesdfwergfwr",
    "place2" : "sgfertgryrctshyctrhysdthc ",
    "place3" : "sdfsdgfrdgfvk",
    "place4" : "asdfkjaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefjnhwklegvds."
  }
}
```

I have thousands of these in my collection. I need to look through all the someotherdata and do the following

1. Check to see if it is present (in some records i have place1 and not place4)
2. Find the longest record (in terms of string length)

The output must look something like this (showing the count of characters for the longest)

```
{   
  place1: 123,
  place2: 12,
  place3: 17
  place4: 445
}
```

I'am using Mongodb 3.2.9 so don't have access to the new aggregate functions. But I do have the Mongodb shell

EDIT: To be clear I want the longest throughout the whole collection. So there might be 1000 documents but only one result with the longest length for each field throughout the whole collection.

Comment: Without access to `$strLenBytes` or `$strLenCP` you would need to use `mapReduce` and return the length of each property using JavaScript functions. It's not really clear if you are asking for the "longest length of each key" through the whole collection, or "just the length of each key per document", or even really what the output should be. For example, you show a document with 4 possible keys and only output for 3.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.mapReduce()` for this to reduce down to the largest values for each key:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(null,
      Object.keys(this.someotherdata).map(k => ({ [k]: this.someotherdata[k].length }))
       .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{})
    );
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var result = {};
    values.forEach(value => {
      Object.keys(value).forEach(k => {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(k))
          result[k] = 0;
        if ( value[k] > result[k] )
          result[k] = value[k];
      });
    });
    return result;
  },
  { 
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "query": { "someotherdata": { "$exists": true } }
  }
)
```

Which basically emits the `"length"` of each key present in the sub-document path for each document, and then in "reduction", only the largest `"length"` for each key is actually returned.

Note that in `mapReduce` you need to put out the same structure you put in, since the way it deals with a large number of documents is by "reducing" in gradual batches. Which is why we `emit` in numeric form, just like the `"reduce"` function does.

Gives this output on your document shown in the question. Of course it's the "max" on all documents in the collection when you have more.

```
   {
        "_id" : null,
        "value" : {
            "place1" : 25.0,
            "place2" : 26.0,
            "place3" : 13.0,
            "place4" : 38.0
        }
    }
```

---

For the interested, the context of the question is in fact that features of MongoDB 3.4 were not available to them. But to do the same thing using `.aggregate()` where the features are available:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "someotherdata": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "someotherdata": {
      "$map": { 
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$someotherdata" },
        "as": "s",
        "in": { "k": "$$s.k", "v": { "$strLenCP": "$$s.v" } }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$someotherdata" },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": "$someotherdata.k",
     "v": { "$max": "$someotherdata.v" }    
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" }
    }    
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": "$data"   
    } 
  }}
])
```

With the same output:

```
{
    "place1" : 25,
    "place2" : 26,
    "place3" : 13,
    "place4" : 38
}
```

Comment: When I run in the ROBO 3T mongo shell it says "Error: Line 6: Unexpected token ;"

Comment: @32423hjh32423 My Bad. Missing a parentheses.

Comment: Says Failed to execute script.

Error: map reduce failed:{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "TypeError: this.someotherdata[k] is null :\n_funcs1/<@:3:45\n_funcs1@:3:7\n",
 "code" : 139
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.mapReduce@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1411:1
@(shell):1:1

Comment: @32423hjh32423 Well is the field actually called `"someotherdata"`? Because **it is in your question**. If you have different data to what you have in the question, then those changes are on **you** and not the people who answer. I can add an `$exists` to discard documents where the field is not present, but it's up to you to use the correct naming.

Comment: I understand the naming issue you mention, I have changed the name but I have compensated for that. It is just a straight swap for what is there. I think an $exists would be useful as I think that is why it is failing because of differences between the items in the collection. Thank you

Comment: the filed is actually called content - but that is the only difference.

Comment: @32423hjh32423 Dude I added the query condition an hour ago. The output is included in the question based on what you actually provided in your question. So the code obviously works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cursor.forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) to iterate through the collection.
Keep track of the longest place*n* values (starting from -1, updating when greater found). Print out values with `print()` or `printjson()`